# In Django, how can I view all the properties of my user?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I do something like:

```
print request.user.is_authenticated()
```

Then True is printed.  However

```
print request.user
```

just prints the username even though 'request.user' is definitely not just a string.  How can I get all user properties to be printed to the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways, e.g.:

```
print dir(request.user)
```

or (this is probably preferred)

```
print request.user.__dict__
```

or (see stalk's extended answer, basically does what `__dict__` does)

```
print ["{0}: {1}".format(field.name, getattr(request.user, field.name)) for field in request.user._meta.fields]
```

or (if you just want methods)

```
print [attr for attr in dir(request.user) if callable(attr)]
```

Comment: In current Django versions (as of 2023), the `user.__dict__` attribute only provides a couple of object references, not a list of properties.  However the `dir(request.user)` function does provide the complete list, so this is still a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
print request.user
```

Model method `__unicode__` is called and it is printed, what it returns. To get the model field, it is needed to access it explicitly:

```
print request.user.field_name
```

To iterate over all fields, this hook can be used:

```
for f in request.user._meta.fields:
    print f.name, getattr(request.user, f.name)
```